# An error: Vector subscript out of range, drill from book "Programming Principles And Practice Using C++" below the session 4.7 Language features

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

double sum(std::vector<double>); //sum of all the values in meter
double conversion(double, std::string); //convert from other units to meter
void print_largest_value(double, std::string); 
void print_smallest_value(double, std::string);

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> temps;      //for storing the numbers entered
    std::vector<std::string> units; //for storing the units entered
    std::vector<double> vals;       //for storing values in meter converted 
    double temp, smallest_val, largest_val, smallest_temp, largest_temp; 
    std::string unit = " ", unit_of_smallest, unit_of_largest;
    int i;
    for (temp, i = 0; std::cin >> temp >> unit; ++i) {
        if (unit == "cm" || unit == "in" || unit == "ft" || unit == "m") {
            temps.push_back(temp);
            units.push_back(unit);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "reject value\n";  //value get rejected if unit not valid
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        vals[i] = conversion(temp, unit); //error: Array index out of bounds
        std::cout << temp << unit << '\n';
        std::cout << vals[i] << " meter(s)\n";
        if (i == 0) {
        smallest_val = vals[i];
        smallest_temp = temps[i];
        unit_of_smallest = unit[i];
        print_smallest_value(temps[i], units[i]);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            largest_val = vals[i];
            largest_temp = temps[i];
            unit_of_largest = unit[i];
            print_largest_value(temps[i], units[i]);
        }
        if (smallest_val > vals[i]) {
            smallest_val = vals[i];
            smallest_temp = temps[i];
            unit_of_smallest = unit[i];
            print_smallest_value(temps[i], units[i]);
        }
        if (largest_val < vals[i]) {
            largest_val = vals[i];
            largest_temp = temps[i];
            unit_of_largest = unit[i];
            print_largest_value(temps[i], units[i]);
        }   
    }
    std::cout << "the sum is: " << sum(vals) << " meter(s)\n";
    std::cout << "the largest value entered is " << largest_temp << unit_of_largest << '\n';
    std::cout << "the smallest value entered is " << smallest_temp << unit_of_smallest << '\n';
}

double sum(std::vector<double> v) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double x : v)
        sum += x;
    return sum;
}

double conversion(double val, std::string unit) {
    if (unit == "cm")
        val /= 100;
    else if (unit == "in")
        val /= 39.3701;
    else if (unit == "ft")
        val /= 3.28084;
    return val;
}

void print_largest_value(double val, std::string unit) {
    std::cout << "the largest value so far: " << val << unit << '\n';
}

void print_smallest_value(double val, std::string unit) {
    std::cout << "the smallest value so far: " << val << unit << '\n';
}
```

/*
7. Add a unit to each double entered; that is, enter values such as 10cm, 2.5in, 5ft, or 3.33m. Accept the four units: cm,
m, in, ft. Assume conversion factors 1m == 100cm, 1in == 2.54cm, 1ft == 12in. Read the unit indicator into a string.
You may consider 12 m (with a space between the number and the unit) equivalent to 12m (without a space).
8. Reject values without units or with “illegal” representations of units, such as y, yard, meter, km, and gallons.
9. Keep track of the sum of values entered (as well as the smallest and the largest) and the number of values entered. When
the loop ends, print the smallest, the largest, the number of values, and the sum of values. Note that to keep the sum, you
have to decide on a unit to use for that sum; use meters.
*/

Comment: What do you expect the size of `vals` to be at the time of the error? What is the actual size at that time?

Comment: When I input, for example, 3in. The error window pops out. So, it is at the very beginning when the program inserts a variable of type double into vals[0]. So I expect the size of vals to be one.

Comment: "So I expect the size of vals to be one" -- why? Where does it become one?

Comment: Oh no, I should use the vals.push_back(conversion(temp,unit)).

Comment: Does anyone know what when the program assign unit[i] to unit_of_smallest or unit_of_largest, unit_of_smallest or unit_of_largest only contains the first character of the string. For example, if unit[i] contains "in" and it is assigned to unit_of_smallest, the unit_of_smallest string only has the first character that is "i".

Comment: @Herman - You have both `unit` and `units`. `units[i]` gives you one of the strings in the vector, while `unit[i]` similarly gives you one of the characters in the string.

Comment: It was actually a typo by me. I intended to type units[i]. But it is interesting because I guess I would not know that unit[i] would give you a character because unit is a string. So I guess if I assign unit[1] to a char or string type variable, it will assign a 2nd character of the string.